# How to call #pragma segment Foo on Garnet OS

Tags: pragma, palm-os, palm, segment

I've read this excellent tutorial about segments in palm:

http://onboardc.sourceforge.net/UsersManual.html#segments

But developing with Garnet OS Development Suite, the command "#pragma segment Foo" isn't recognized by the compiler, it warns me: "Warning: ignoring pragma"

Is there an option to enable this pragma segment?

Answer (score 0):

`#pragma` directives are always compiler-dependent.  The tutorial you're reading is specifically about the OnBoard C compiler.

IIRC, the Garnet OS (nee Palm OS) Development Suite (do they now refer to it as GODS instead of PODS now?) is based on prc-tools.  You can [check the prc-tools documentation about using multiple segments](http://prc-tools.sourceforge.net/doc/prc-tools_3.html#SEC17).  If you're using Eclipse, I think it's supposed to let you create multi-segmented applications. (I've never personally used that, however.  I did find [a page with some notes about the process](http://tamspalm.tamoggemon.com/2007/02/27/creating-multi-segment-applications-with-pods/).)

The old Palm OS Programming FAQ also describes [some general ways to deal with the 32K limit](http://www.flippinbits.com/twiki/index.php?page=how-to-work-around-limits).